# Get DBUS services list

Tags: d-bus

Using the following command I can get the list of DBUS services.

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus --type=method_call --print-reply /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
```

The output is:

```
method return time=1531507472.618646 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.83 serial=3 reply_serial=2
   array [
      string "org.freedesktop.DBus"
      string "com.canonical.Unity.Launcher"
      string "org.freedesktop.Notifications"
      string ":1.7"
      string "org.freedesktop.network-manager-applet"
      string ":1.8"
      string "com.canonical.indicator.datetime"
      string ":1.9"
      string "org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor"
      string "org.gtk.vfs.mountpoint_2434"
      string "com.canonical.indicator.sound"
      string "org.gtk.vfs.Daemon"
      string "org.pulseaudio.Server"
      string "com.canonical.indicator.application"
      string "com.ubuntu.Upstart"
      string "org.gnome.SessionManager"
      string "com.canonical.hud"
      string "com.canonical.indicator.session"
      string ":1.82"
      string ":1.60"
      string ":1.83"
      string ":1.61"
      string "com.canonical.indicator.messages"
      string "org.gnome.GConf"
      string "org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5"
      string "org.gnome.Terminal"
      string ":1.63"
      string "org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor"
      string "org.a11y.Bus"
      string ":1.64"
      string ":1.42"
      string ":1.20"
      string ":1.65"
      string ":1.43"
      string "org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power"
      string ":1.66"
      string ":1.44"
      string "org.gnome.keyring"
      string "org.gnome.Shell"
      string ":1.67"
      string ":1.45"
      string "com.canonical.Unity.WindowStack"
      string ":1.68"
      string ":1.46"
      string ":1.24"
      string "com.canonical.Unity.Panel.Service.Desktop"
      string ":1.69"
      string "org.gnome.DejaDup.Monitor"
      string ":1.48"
      string ":1.27"
      string ":1.28"
      string "org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor"
      string ":1.29"
      string "ca.desrt.dconf"
      string "com.canonical.indicator.printers"
      string "org.gnome.SettingsDaemon"
      string "org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver"
      string "org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar7"
      string "org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XRANDR"
      string "org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor"
      string "org.ayatana.bamf"
      string "org.freedesktop.FileManager1"
      string "com.canonical.indicator.bluetooth"
      string "org.PulseAudio1"
      string "org.gnome.Nautilus"
      string "org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor"
      string "com.canonical.indicator.keyboard"
      string "com.canonical.Unity"
      string ":1.70"
      string "org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.Calendarx2320x2"
      string ":1.71"
      string "org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.Calendarx2320x3"
      string "org.gnome.ScreenSaver"
      string "org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine"
      string "org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook9"
      string ":1.51"
      string ":1.74"
      string ":1.52"
      string ":1.30"
      string ":1.75"
      string ":1.53"
      string ":1.31"
      string ":1.76"
      string ":1.54"
      string "org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard"
      string ":1.10"
      string ":1.77"
      string "org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.AddressBookx2463x2"
      string ":1.55"
      string ":1.11"
      string ":1.33"
      string ":1.78"
      string ":1.56"
      string ":1.12"
      string "com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar"
      string ":1.34"
      string "org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher"
      string ":1.79"
      string ":1.57"
      string ":1.0"
      string ":1.13"
      string ":1.35"
      string ":1.58"
      string ":1.1"
      string ":1.14"
      string ":1.36"
      string "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub"
      string ":1.59"
      string ":1.37"
      string "org.freedesktop.secrets"
      string ":1.2"
      string ":1.15"
      string "org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor"
      string ":1.38"
      string ":1.3"
      string ":1.16"
      string "org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer"
      string ":1.4"
      string ":1.5"
      string "org.gnome.Software"
      string "com.canonical.indicator.power"
      string "org.freedesktop.IBus"
      string ":1.6"
   ]
```

But I don't see the **com.canonical.Unity.Session** (or other for gnome) service.

Using  **com.canonical.Unity.Session** service I can handle screen lock\unlock. I'm using it in my program, which will get the photo of man, who unlocked the screen. So at this moment this program works only on that machine, which is using **com.canonical.Unity.Session** service.

The question:
How can I dynamically get the service as a string for my program?

PS. The link on the file, which is using DBUS
https://github.com/alkhachatryan/spyonspies/blob/master/autorun.sh

Comment: I'm looking for `colord` and I didn't find it as well.